# Creating an encoded polygon for google maps in PHP

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I'm just wondering how I can convert points into an encoded polygon for static google maps.

I will be retrieving the data from MySQL as a multipolygon, however I can rearrange the data as needed.

I simply need a good php script that can encode the polygon.

I realize this may seem like a duplicate question, but I have searched everywhere and cannot find anything. There are multiple scripts on-line however there is no documentation as how the array of points is to be formatted and ect.

These include

- https://code.google.com/p/opencaching-pl/source/browse/trunk/lib/class.polylineEncoder.php?r=4122

OR

- https://github.com/jfsimon/GMapBundle/blob/master/Encoder/PolylineEncoder.php

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the definitive reference: http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/

With a link to a [PHP implementationby Jim Hribar](http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/PolylineEncoder.php.txt)

`you asked:` How do I format it. e.g array(array(xcoord,ycoord),array(xcoord,ycoord));

Looking at the source of both the examples you reference, I see something like this:
(from the second):

```
 $lat = $points[$i][0];
 $lng = $points[$i][1];
```

What else do you need to know?

Comment: Thanks - I had seen this though, but there doesn't seem to be any info on the format of the array. There is a lot of information for the javascript side of it, but not the PHP. How do I format it. e.g array(array(xcoord,ycoord),array(xcoord,ycoord));

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that...  The format worked correctly, though it seemed to need a few other variables. Either way that format correctly worked with a script from Gabriel which I have posted also.

Comment: Jim Hribar's implementation link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Using the previous answer I managed to find a solution which did explain the process and worked quite well.

If others are looking to do the same thing, you can use a script made by Gabriel Svennerberg.

The link is:
http://www.svennerberg.com/2008/11/polylines-in-google-maps-part-2/